# MySQL error with Wordpress, running on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, xampp, elementor

So I was creating a website in wordpress using Elementor page for a school project, and suddenly when I UPDATED the page (using Elementor builder), the site crashed. I tried everything including deleting the **ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and aria_log_control** files in my XAMPP (Yes, I'm using XAMPP for Windows) and it still crashes when I try to load into website/wordpress control panel. Can somebody help me fix it? The project is due two days...
Crash report:

```
2022-05-27 19:36:44 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2022-05-27 19:36:44 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2022-05-27 19:36:44 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-05-27 19:36:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-05-27 19:36:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-05-27 19:36:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-05-27 19:36:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-05-27 19:36:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-05-27 19:36:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-05-27 19:36:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-05-27 19:36:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-05-27 19:36:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-05-27 19:36:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-05-27 19:36:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-05-27 19:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-05-27 19:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 46991441; transaction id 16292
2022-05-27 19:36:49 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-05-27 19:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from G:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-05-27 19:36:49 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2022-05-27 19:36:49 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2022-05-27 19:36:49 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2022-05-27 19:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220527 19:36:49
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x55ae)
```

Comment: Have you checked in \xampp\mysql\data? Check for files that look like aria_ log.000x. And do not forget to restart xampp after that. Also you shouldn't have deleted aria_log_control.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same failure. Try deleting the aria log files. Goto xamp\mysql\data.
After I deleted them mysql was running again.